# For loop with table which return 12 values (month)

Tags: php, arrays

I write this code when I try to return 12 numbers from 1 to 12:

```
public function getMonths() 
{ 
    for($monthNum = 1; $monthNum <= 12; $monthNum++)
        { 
          $month[$monthNum]=$monthNum;
        } 
return [$month]; 
}
```

How can I return this 12 numbers? I have now zero in my first return value. Anyone know how to resolve this? I need only 12 numbers without 0?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I agree with you that this not a good question. But actually the code is not syntactically incorrect, because you don't have to initialize in array in PHP. It is automatically created when you make an assignment.

Comment: I haven't written php in too long to remember, but what do you get if you return $month instead of [$month]?

Comment: @JeroenNoten My mistake, I haven't written PHP in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to write `return $month;` instead of `return [$month]`, otherwise you are wrapping your `$month` array in another array while returning it.

Comment: Yes that is this, this was easy but i am stupid. Thank You, have a good day